# What's the impact of not using MyBase.OnInit(e) when overriding it in a derived class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm inheriting from TextBox and overriding OnInit.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)

MyBase.OnInit(e) 

' I'm adding a dynamic control to go along with my textbox here...
Controls.Add(Something)

End Sub
```

I have MyBase.OnInit(e) in the example above, but I've been using my control for a while without it, as I forgot to put it in there. This is something I usually do out of habit, so I never gave its purpose much thought:

> When overriding OnInit in a derived class, be sure to call the base
>   class’s OnInit method so that registered delegates receive the event.

Slightly embarrassing that this isn't clear to me, but my control works fine, so I was just hoping someone could give an example of what could create an issue.

Comment: I would imagine it breaks code which is listening for the `OnInit` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) for `TextBox`, if you follow the inheritance up to `Control`, you see this is the base code for [`OnInit`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/Control.cs,1691):

```
protected internal virtual void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    if(HasEvents()) {
        EventHandler handler = _events[EventInit] as EventHandler;
        if(handler != null) {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

So if you don't call `base.OnInit`, this is what will be missed.

Comment: Right. I understood this at a basic level, but not sure of what type of "Event" would cause a problem. For example, OnTextChange is an event, but you would also call the base OnTextChange. Or if I add a handler to something within my class definition ( which I did also ), it had no issues either, even though I forgot to call MyBase.OnInit(e). So I know your answer is correct, but I obviously don't fully understand it.

Comment: I guess the point is that there are other things listening to the events. If you miss out the base calls, then odd things *might* happen. So unless you specifically know what you are doing, I would always put them in there.

Comment: Absolutely agree, and it wasn't until I forgot to put it in there, only to notice it a month later, that I wondered why all was well. So now I'm on a mission to fully digest yet another intricate part of Microsoft. Seems this is never ending.